# Not possible open "Component Manager"

Tags: magento-2.1

I buy extension from marketplace.magento and try to install via component manager in backend magento v.2.1.11

Unfortunately, when I choose this,the page non-stop loading "Please wait".

I tried to change the browser and clean cache browser but nothing helps.

[image]

Comment: Generally when you are stuck on a spinning "Please Wait" screen an error occurred in one of the ajax calls that build the page.

Comment: To troubleshoot I suggest going to your browser's developer tools and checking the Network tab when you reload the page. This should show which request fails / never finishes.

Comment: Additional errors might be logged in your server'/s php's error logs - add them here and people might be able to help further.

Comment: Also, if you have some cache / optimization layer in between with too aggressive optimization, e.g. some filters for mod_pagespeed, it could fail.